# Swift ios only pick string values from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, alamofire

In my app I have an array that looks like this:

```
var imgArray = [(Data, String)]()
```

It holds images and the images names and I append data by doing this:

```
if let firstImage = self.firstImage {
                if let firstImageData = firstImage.compressImage() {
                    self.imgArray.append(firstImageData, self.randomImageName(length: 15))
                }
            }
```

Now I need to send all the image names inside that array using alamofire and I tried this:

```
for imgName in self.imgArray {
                parameters["images[]"] = imgName.1
            }
```

But my server responds by saying that `images[]` is empty, so I think that my ios code never sends an array named `images[]` containing the image names

**Update**
I changed the parameter to this:

```
parameters["images"] = [imgName.1]
```

This will upload one image, it seems like it overwrites the value each time so I need a way to grap all Strings from the imgArray array

Comment: What do you see on debugger? Does `imgName.1` really empty?

Comment: Please explain last line 'parameters["images[]"] = imgName.1' bit more

Comment: Most of your posted code doesn't look like it will even compile.

Comment: @rmaddy everything compiles

Comment: @VladimirKaltyrin it was not empty but my parameter was spelled wrong, I should have leaved out the "[]" bit from the name

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I try to add a parameter to my request containing the image name

Comment: @Kiow No, your code doesn't compile. You have an array of tuples. But your use of `append` isn't actually appending a tuple. You are missing a set of parentheses.

Comment: @rmaddy Well I changed my code based on the answer i got to: ``parameters["images"] = imgArray.map{$0.1}`` and now it works fine. I am picking a image and uploading it to my server just tested it so it compiles just fine

Comment: Consider this Apple statement: *Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.*

Comment: @vadian if not using Tuples to store images and image names that should be sent how should I else store them?

Comment: ***... model it as a class or structure***

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
parameters["images"] = imgArray.map{$0.1}
```

This will add all of the image names from `imgArray`